# Simple jQuery not working in Rail 3.2

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This one has had me going for a couple of hours now. Any help would be appreciated, let me know if I can provide any more information.

I am trying to get some basic jQuery working in my Rails 3.2 application. The jQuery in question is to provide an action on a button press (at the moment, just an alert dialog to know it's working).

**app/views/orders/index.html.erb**

```
...

<button type="button" class="btn" id="button">My button</button>

...
```

I have tried a number of variations for the jQuery/JS code, including...

**apps/assets/javascripts/orders.js**

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    alert("Test message");
});
```

.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click(function() {
        alert("Test message");
    });
});
```

.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').button();
    $('#button').click(function() {
        $(this).button('loading');
    });
});
```

Some points to note:

- This is running in the development env
- The JS file is showing up in the source and in the Chrome network/resources panel without errors.
- I've tried re-ordering my application.js file.
- I am not adept with CoffeeScript yet, but am willing to try a CoffeeScript based solution.
- Chrome reports an error in Morris.

My **app/assets/javascripts/application.js** for reference

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require raphael
//= require morris
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Any suggestions on steps to take to track down this bug would be very helpful!

---

**Updates**

Tried the following CoffeeScript solution with no luck.

```
jQuery ->
    jQuery('#button').click ->
        alert("Test msg")

// ... which generates ...

(function() {

  jQuery(function() {
    return jQuery('#jamcake').click(function() {
      return alert("You have cake?");
    });
  });

}).call(this);
```

Tried changing button to a link, to no avail.

Tried going back to basics, the following works.

```
alert("Hello");
```

However, the following does not...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("Hello there");
});
```

Comment: One quick thing to check is if you have multiple elements with the `id` of `button`. The click event might be binding to something else. Another note: the second code block in what you've tested is what you should be using.

Comment: What does Chrome say about Morris and what happens if you leave it out?

Comment: @DavidKiger Thanks for the tip, ID has been changed. Re-tests with the same result however.

Comment: @muistooshort The error be: 'Uncaught Error: Graph container element not found'. Removed everything par jquery, _ujs and tree .. Still the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

A shot in the dark, but one of the other js libraries could be conflicting with jQuery's use of `$`

Try:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // code here, using $ as usual

  $('#button').click(function() {
    alert("Test message");
  });
});
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you!  I let out a big "DOH!" when I saw this.

Answer (score 0):

.html

```
<button type="button" class="btn" id="first-test">My button</button>
```

.js

```
$(function() {
   $("button#first-test").on("click",function() {     
     alert(hi); 
   });            
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one and check the console to make sure: The event is firing and that jQuery can find the element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log($('#button').size());
});
```

If you get nothing you might have a conflict or the error with the other library is preventing the rest of the script to run.

Comment: Brilliant! Nothing is getting reported back, so the event isn't firing in the first place. Is this indeed pointing to a conflict as you said then?

Comment: Now try removing the **require morris** from your **app/assets/javascripts/application.js** and check the browser console. If you get something then your conflict is related to morris.